# MYSQL Slow SELECT with multiple joins and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, query-performance

I have this query

```
SELECT 
r0_.id AS id0,
r0_.deleted_at AS deleted_at1,
r0_.updated_at AS updated_at2,
r0_.created_at AS created_at3,
r0_.is_vehicle_offer AS is_vehicle_offer4,
r0_.vehicle_offer_price AS vehicle_offer_price5,
r0_.vehicle_offer_description AS vehicle_offer_description6,
r0_.nr_of_parts_found_mails_sent AS nr_of_parts_found_mails_sent7,
r0_.client_id AS client_id8,
r0_.parent_id AS parent_id9,
r0_.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id10 
FROM 
requests r0_ 
INNER JOIN vehicles v1_ ON r0_.vehicle_id = v1_.id 
INNER JOIN sibren_brands s2_ ON v1_.sibren_brand_id = s2_.id 
INNER JOIN member_sibben_brands_subscriptions m4_ ON s2_.id =m4_.sibren_brand_id 
INNER JOIN members m3_ ON m3_.id = m4_.member_id 
INNER JOIN member_vehicle_categories m6_ ON m3_.id = m6_.member_id 
INNER JOIN vehicle_categories v5_ ON v5_.id = m6_.vehicle_category_id 
INNER JOIN member_sibren_brands_filter m8_ ON s2_.id = m8_.sibren_brand_id 
INNER JOIN members m7_ ON m7_.id = m8_.member_id 
LEFT JOIN request_metadata r9_ ON r0_.id = r9_.request_id AND (r9_.member_id = '210')
WHERE m3_.id = '210' AND v5_.id = s2_.vehicle_category_id AND
m7_.id = '210' AND r0_.updated_at >= '2012-04-19 13:31:26' AND
(r9_.id IS NULL OR r9_.deleted_at IS NULL) AND
r0_.updated_at <= '2012-06-19 13:31:25' 
GROUP BY r0_.id 
ORDER BY r0_.updated_at DESC 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

Wich takes about 1.5 secs to run.  If I remove the last part GROUP BY .etc.....
than it only takes 0.07 sec.

Here's the result of EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  m3_ const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  m7_ const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  m6_ ref PRIMARY,vehicle_category_id,member_id   PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  v5_ eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   oz_nl.m6_.vehicle_category_id   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  s2_ ref PRIMARY,vehicle_category_id vehicle_category_id 4   oz_nl.m6_.vehicle_category_id   37  Using index
1   SIMPLE  m4_ eq_ref  PRIMARY,sibren_brand_id,member_id   PRIMARY 8   const,oz_nl.s2_.id  1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  m8_ eq_ref  PRIMARY,sibren_brand_id,member_id   PRIMARY 8   const,oz_nl.s2_.id  1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  v1_ ref PRIMARY,sibren_brand_id sibren_brand_id 5   oz_nl.s2_.id    111 Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  r0_ ref vehicle_id,updated_at   vehicle_id  4   oz_nl.v1_.id    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  r9_ eq_ref  request_id,member_id,request_id_2   request_id  8   oz_nl.r0_.id,const  1   Using where
```

As far as i can see indexes are set OK

Comment: Don't know how....

Comment: It would be preferable if you posted the EXPLAIN output with \G at the end instead of ; for a vertical layout, which is much more readable.

Comment: I'm very curious why do you need numbering your output columns?  It doesn't help too much with readability...

Comment: I see a GROUP BY, but no aggregate functions. So I wonder what the purpose of the GROUP BY is. Does it have any effect on the result at all? (I am not a MySQL specialist)

Comment: Hi Harmstra, welcome to the site! What version of MySQL? What are the hardware specs of the server (RAM, Disk setup, etc)? Can you show the DDL of at least the `members` and `requests` tables?

Answer (score 2):

The issue that jumps out at me is the first table in your `EXPLAIN`:

```
1   SIMPLE  m3_ const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

As you've noticed, if you remove the `GROUP BY...ORDER BY...`, the query runs much faster. Doing so most likely removes the `Using temporary;Using filesort` (but I can't know for sure without the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

I would suspect this is creating the temporary table **on disk**. See [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) on how MySQL uses temporary tables.

First, if you are selecting any BLOB or TEXT columns, this will automatically be an on-disk temporary table. From your list, it looks like `r0_.vehicle_offer_description AS vehicle_offer_description6` could fit the bill.

If this is the case, try removing that column and see if there is any noticeable difference.

Comment: I could post the table structure here but that's a lot of info cause some tables have lotst of fields

Comment: @Harmstra - there is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), a very convenient online tool for posting lots of SQL code.